# How to set attribute default to the current post title value in Gutenberg custom block?

Tags: block-editor

Is it possible to set custom Gutenberg block attributes default to inherit the post title until you start to edit it?

```
    "attributes": {
        "message": {
            "type": "string",
            "source": "text",
            "selector": "div",
            "default": ???
        }
```

Comment: I think the closest you can get to this is setting the attribute when the block is inserted. Though it might be better to avoid setting the attribute and instead substitute the post title in case the attribute is still the default. I say that because it’s a bit simpler and on the frontend you may want the "default" to be dynamic and saving the attribute wouldn't be.